# how to access helper when building ActionView manually and not from a Rails Controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-3.2, actionview

I have a class (not a controller) that generates external javascript that we then store in redis and am using Rails 3.2.19. One of the views calls a helper that is located in application_helper but it is now erroring out saying that it can't find the helper.

I would think that calling ActionView::Base.new would bring in the helpers from application_helper.rb but it doesn't appear to by default. However, on production on heroku, this does work as anticipated. I guess the question is what is the path for the views created via ActionView::Base.new?

I have:

```
class MenuGenerator
  def self.js_external(id)
    @menu=Menu.find(id)
    str=ActionView::Base.new(
        Rails.configuration.paths["app/views"]).render(
        :partial => 'api/get_menu_3',
        :locals => { :menu => @menu, :format => 'div' })
    key='menus/' + id.to_s + '/js-external'
    $redis.set(key, str)
    return str
  end
```

and have tried including my application_helper via

```
 def self.js_external(id)
    include ApplicationHelper
    @menu=Menu.find(id)
```

or

```
class MenuGenerator
  include ApplicationHelper
```

but neither works. What woudl I need to add to make this helper accessible by my view?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do with `MenuGenerator ` class? What is the purpose? is this for view or for storing data in db?

Comment: prebuild an external javascript file for an external user. It is called from a sidekiq job

Comment: After a wild laugh I realized this is actually a nice question, because it needs some deeper rails insights.
I don't have time to dig in right now, but I'd suggest read the rails code and try to find out what the rails guys actually called to render a view.
I'll keep track of this question, because I don't get why it would work on Heroku but not localy..

Comment: @Ninigi yeah, was a bit wierd. I actually just ended up putting the functionality in models and called it a day. Life's too short